# How can I edit the height of my tables in Magento?

Tags: layout, rwd, magento-1.9

I'm trying to change the height of my table which is located in the product-shop class. 
catalog - > product -> view.phtml. The problem is that I can set the height to higher numbers but not to lower ones.

[image]

[image]

The height is always fixed if I want to set it to lower numbers but I can increase the high. What can I do to set the height to lower numbers? I tried to set the height to lower numbers in css and in html code but it doesn't work - the table will always stay at this height.

Comment: What's your url?

Comment: Are you able to provide more info like the styles that are being generated for this?

Comment: How you are setting height ? by using height or min-height ?

Comment: @MineshPatel by height.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri running on a localhost - is there a way I can run it online for free?

Comment: @rob3000 what do you mean by "styles are being generated for this" ?

Comment: @ercMatha are you able to paste your html/js/styles in the question so that we can see more.